# Python csv file writing in different columns

Tags: python, csv

Im trying to read a csv file, and create a new cvs file, with the contents of the old cvs file with Python. My Problem is, that all entrys are saved in the first column, and i cant find a way to save the informations in different columns. Here is my code:

```
import csv
from itertools import zip_longest

fieldnamesOrdered = ['First Name', 'Last Name' , 'Email', 'Phone Number', 
'Street Address', 'City', 'State', 'HubSpot Owner', 'Lifecyle Stage', 'Lead 
 Status', 'Favorite Color']

listOne = []
listTwo = []

with open('Contac.csv', 'r', encoding = 'utf-8') as inputFile, 
open('result.csv', 'w', encoding = 'utf-8') as outputFile:

    reader = csv.DictReader(inputFile)
    writer = csv.writer(outputFile, delimiter = 't')
    for row in reader:
        listOne.append(row['First Name'])
        listTwo.append(row['Last Name'])

    dataLists = [listOne, listTwo]
    export_data = zip_longest(*dataLists, fillvalue='')
    writer.writerow(fieldnamesOrdered)
    writer.writerows(export_data)

inputFile.close()
outputFile.close()
```

Thank you very much for your answers

Comment: Could you fix the indentation?

Comment: and the missing colon on `with open`

Comment: @manandearth there is no missing colon on open - its after the second open.

Comment: oh, yes of course..somehow the tabscore doesnt work here, i need to put 4 spaces in each row. im fixing it

Comment: can you post a sample of the csv file?

Comment: Its solved arleady - the `'\t'` is missing its `'\'` - @bipll found it and answered .... so the `writer` uses `t` as delimiter - simple typo

Answer (score 1):

```
writer = csv.writer(outputFile, delimiter = 't')
```

Aren't those entries in the first column additionally interspersed with strange unsolicited 't' characters?

Comment: right, thats a typo. Thanks very much! anyways, it doesnt solve my problem, since now, in excel at least all the items are not having any spaces at all. Everything is still saved in one column. Maybe i am using the wrong format with utf-8?